# how to get user info from jdbc user service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-mybatis

i am using spring security authorization to secure user login to my application by using the following code:

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password as password,1 as enabled FROM users  WHERE username=?" authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority,1 as enabled FROM users WHERE username =?" />
```

is there any way to add other fields to this query ex:ID,Email ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load complete Custom user object from database, and then to set it in `SecurityContextHolder`/`Session`, the better approach would be to use custom UserDetailService

### Create a Custom user Entity:

First create a simple Custom user Entity according to your database table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class SecurityUser implements Serializable{  

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    //Gettters & Setters plus Default constructor
}
```

### Create a repository/DAO for accessing above User from database

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<SecurityUser, Long> {
    SecurityUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

### Create a custom user object for logged in user extending Spring's `User`

```
public class CurrentUser extends User {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SecurityUser securityUser;

    public CurrentUser(SecurityUser securityUser) {
        super(securityUser.getUsername(), securityUser.getPassword(), AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(securityUser.getRole().toString()));
        this.securityUser = securityUser;
    }

    public SecurityUser getSecurityUser() {
        return securityUser;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return securityUser.getRole();
    }
}
```

### Create a Custom User Detail Service

```
@Service
public class CurrentUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userService;

    @Autowired
    public CurrentUserDetailsService(UserRepository userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public CurrentUserDetailsService() {

    }

    @Override
    public CurrentUser loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        SecurityUser user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        return new CurrentUser(user);
    }
}
```

### Set UserDetailService in Configuration

As you are using XML based configuration, so do something like this in config file:

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService"
  class="complete-path-to-serviceClasss.MyUserDetailsService"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
      user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
        </security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Now anywhere, if you execute below lines when user is loggedin, it will give you `CurrentUser` object with all data

```
CurrentUser user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only for authentication, after the user is logged in, you can check for the logged in user like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="loggedInUser", method={RequestMethod.GET}, produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public User getLoggedInUser(Principal principal) throws SQLException{
        return database.getUser(principal.getName());
    }
```

Or you can just return username with `principal.getName()`